# RoboCopy Log File

Tags: c#, logging, robocopy

Does anyone have any C# code that would help format the robocopy log file for easier upload to a database.

Sample log

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Thu Jul 07 12:00:12 2011

   Source : C:\Sales\Out\
     Dest : \\Marketing\Data\In\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /MOV /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                       0     C:\Sales\In\
      *EXTRA File          1.4 m    2011MarketingMaster.XLS
      *EXTRA File          1.3 m    2011SalesOutput 01 .XLS
      *EXTRA File          1.4 m    2011SalesOutput 02 .XLS
      *EXTRA File          1.4 m    2011SalesOutput 03 .XLS
      *EXTRA File          1.4 m    2011SalesOutput 04 .XLS
      *EXTRA File          1.4 m    2011SalesOutput 05 .XLS
      *EXTRA File          1.4 m    2011SalesOutput 06 .XLS
      *EXTRA File          1.4 m    2011SalesOutput 07 .XLS
      *EXTRA File          1.4 m    2011SalesOutput 08 .XLS
      *EXTRA File          1.4 m    2011SalesOutput 09 .XLS
      *EXTRA File          1.4 m    2011SalesOutput 10 .XLS
      *EXTRA File          1.4 m    2011SalesOutput 11 .XLS
      *EXTRA File          1.4 m    2011SalesOutput 12 .XLS

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         0         0         0         0         0       13
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0  461.67 m
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00

   Ended : Thu Jul 07 12:00:12 2011
```

Comment: There's a bunch of potential data for export here. What part(s) are you interested in? Do you have a table schema that the data should fit into?

Comment: What information do you need out of the log file? What is you database structure?

Comment: I am interested in the Job Summary only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in the files only, using the /NJH (no job header) and /NJS (no job summary) switches might make your work a lot easier: [MSDN: Robocopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145)

Answer (score 0):

I found this [sketchingdev blog post](https://sketchingdev.co.uk/blog/powershell-extract-the-summary-table-from-robocopys-log-file.html) to be useful.

It creates a PowerShell (`PSObject`) so from there manipulating and uploading to a database should be easier.

also, a very much [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29393153/11089361) with answer to the original question: interested in the Job Summary only