# Parsing robocopy log file to PSCustomObject

Tags: parsing, powershell, text

I'm trying to create a `PSCustomObject` from a robocopy log file. The first piece is pretty easy but I'm struggling with the `$Footer` part. I can't seem to find a good way to split up the values.

It would be nice if every entry has it's own `Property`, so it's possible to use for example `$Total.Dirs` or `$Skipped.Dirs`. I was thinking about `Import-CSV`, because that's just great on how it allows you to have column headers. But this doesn't seem to fit here. There's another solution I found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timid/archive/2013/03/05/converting-pscustomobject-to-from-hashtables.aspx) but it seems a bit of overkill.

**Code:**

```
Function ConvertFrom-RobocopyLog {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,Position=0)]
        [String]$LogFile
    )

    Process {
        $Header = Get-Content $LogFile | select -First 10
        $Footer = Get-Content $LogFile | select -Last 7

        $Header | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -like "*Source*") {$Source = (($_.Split(':'))[1]).trim()}
            if ($_ -like "*Dest*")   {$Destination = (($_.Split(':'))[1]).trim()}
        }

        $Footer | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -like "*Dirs*") {$Dirs = (($_.Split(':'))[1]).trim()}
            if ($_ -like "*Files*") {$Files = (($_.Split(':'))[1]).trim()}
            if ($_ -like "*Times*") {$Times = (($_.Split(':'))[1]).trim()}
        }

        $Obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Source'      = $Source
                'Destination' = $Destination
                'Dirs'        = $Dirs
                'Files'       = $Files
                'Times'       = $Times
        }               
        Write-Output $Obj
    }
}
```

**Log file:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Wed Apr 01 14:28:11 2015

   Source : \\SHARE\Source\
     Dest : \\SHARE\Target\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /Z /NP /R:3 /W:3 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         0 Files...
         0 More Folders and files...

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         2         0         2         0         0         0
   Files :       203         0       203         0         0         0
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00

   Ended : Wed Apr 01 14:28:12 2015
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I know what you are asking but dont' know what you expect for output. Do you have a property called Dirs that has sub properties for total, copied etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clean this up more but this is the basic approach I would take.

```powershell
Function ConvertFrom-RobocopyLog {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,Position=0)]
        [String]$LogFile
    )

    Process {
        $Header = Get-Content $LogFile | select -First 10
        $Footer = Get-Content $LogFile | select -Last 7

        $Header | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -like "*Source*") {$Source = (($_.Split(':'))[1]).trim()}
            if ($_ -like "*Dest*")   {$Destination = (($_.Split(':'))[1]).trim()}
        }

        $Footer | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -like "*Dirs*"){
                $lineAsArray = (($_.Split(':')[1]).trim()) -split '\s+'
                $Dirs = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                    Total =  $lineAsArray[0]   
                    Copied =  $lineAsArray[1]  
                    Skipped =  $lineAsArray[2]  
                    Mismatch = $lineAsArray[3]     
                    FAILED = $lineAsArray[4]     
                    Extras = $lineAsArray[5] 
                }
            }
            if ($_ -like "*Files*"){
                $lineAsArray = ($_.Split(':')[1]).trim() -split '\s+'
                $Files = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                    Total =  $lineAsArray[0]   
                    Copied =  $lineAsArray[1]  
                    Skipped =  $lineAsArray[2]  
                    Mismatch = $lineAsArray[3]     
                    FAILED = $lineAsArray[4]     
                    Extras = $lineAsArray[5] 
                }
            }
            if ($_ -like "*Times*"){
                $lineAsArray = ($_.Split(':',2)[1]).trim() -split '\s+'
                $Times = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                    Total =  $lineAsArray[0]   
                    Copied =  $lineAsArray[1]     
                    FAILED = $lineAsArray[2]     
                    Extras = $lineAsArray[3] 
                }
            }
        }

        $Obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Source'      = $Source
                'Destination' = $Destination
                'Dirs'        = $Dirs
                'Files'       = $Files
                'Times'       = $Times
        }               
        Write-Output $Obj
    }
}
```

I wanted to make a function to parse the footer lines but `$Times` is a special case since it does not have all the same columns of data.

With `$Times` the **important** difference is how we are doing the split. Since the string contains more than one colon we need to account for that. Using the other paramenter in `.Split()` we specify the number of elements to return.

```powershell
$_.Split(':',2)[1]
```

Since these logs always have output and no blanks row elements we can do this assuming that the parsed elements of `$lineAsArray` will always have 6 elements.

**Sample Output**

```powershell
Source      : \\SHARE\Source\
Destination : \\SHARE\Target\
Dirs        : @{Total=2; Copied=0; Skipped=2; Mismatch=0; FAILED=0; Extras=0}
Files       : @{Total=203; Copied=0; Skipped=203; Mismatch=0; FAILED=0; Extras=0}
Times       : @{Total=0:00:00; Copied=0:00:00; FAILED=0:00:00; Extras=0:00:00}
```

So if you wanted the total files copied you can now use dot notation.

```powershell
(ConvertFrom-RobocopyLog C:\temp\log.log).Files.Total
203
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, you're the boss! I didn't know this (`$_.Split(':',2)`) was possible with `Split`. Really great solution! :) I understand now how it's done.

Comment: A small improvement I added was `Total =  [TimeSpan]$Array[0]`.

Comment: If you need more than one value, save the results to a variable so you only read the log file once: 
    `$robolog = ConvertFrom-RobocopyLog C:\temp\log.log`
    `($robolog).Files.Total` = `203`
    `($robolog).Files.FAILED` = `0`

Answer (score 1):

Not that clear what you want to do, but this will go some way to showing you how to get the stats into an array of objects

```
$statsOut = @()
$stats = Get-Content $LogFile | select -Last 6 | select -first 4

$stats | % {
  $s = $_ -split "\s+"
  $o = new-object -type pscustomobject -property @{"Name"=$s[0];"Total"=$s[2];"Copied"=$s[3];"Skipped"=$s[4];"mismatch"=$s[5]}; 
  $statsOut += ,$o 
}
```

Gives:

```
[PS] > $statsOut | ft -Auto
mismatch Name  Skipped Total   Copied
-------- ----  ------- -----   ------
0        Dirs  2       2       0
0        Files 203     203     0
0        Bytes 0       0       0
```